# Macro replaces non matching criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy/paste formulas in columns where the date is less than today's date.

This goes beyond the criteria and replaces non matching criteria to fit the criteria.

I have a spreadsheet with data from A1:I3. Row 1 contains dates, Rows 2 & 3 contain formulas. The dates in row 1 run from 03/01/22 - 03/09/22.

My macro looks for any dates less than today's date & copies & pastes the formulas as values. This works but the dates in H & I, 03/08/22 and 03/09/22 respectively, are replaced with 03/07/22.

```vb
Dim K As String
K = Date
MsgBox K

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 9
    If (Cells(1, i).Value < K) Then Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Copy
    Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic only checks when copying, but not when pasting.

```
Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

This is executed for every single `i`, regardless of whether `(Cells(1, i).Value < K)` is `True` or `False`.  You need to use the multi-line `If...End If` syntax.

```
If Cells(1, i).Value < K Then 
    Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Copy
    Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```

To make this better though, avoid working with a `String` representation of a date, and bypass the clipboard:

```
If Cells(1, i).Value < Date Then
    Columns(i).Value = Columns(i).Value
End If
```